# how to get value of hidden fields in controller?

Tags: codeigniter, field, hidden

how do i get the value of hidden field from controller?

i tried this:

```
$hidden=$this->input->post('hidden_field_name');
```

it showed error. The field name is correct, i double checked it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$_POST['hidden_field_name']`;

If that doesn't work, then it's because that field_name doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML is right first. If it's not in "View Source" then it's not going to work.

Then:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

If you see the item you want in there, grab it with $this->input->post();

var_dump() is your friend, use it every time you are confused.

Answer (score 0):

very easy !

i have used

```
form_hidden('username', 'johndoe');

// Would produce:

<input type="hidden" name="username" value="johndoe" />
```

and i have got no chance of gettig a POST DATA , sucks :( right?.

It was this change i made it very easy as it should be again.

**Remember: you need to give ID.**

```
<?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='source' id='source' value='addStoreForm' />"; ?>
```

ALLOHA!